# AVR atmega328p - Can I use port C as digital output pins?

Tags: avr, atmega328p, avr-gcc

I'm currently trying to connect a 7x5 dot matrix to an AVR ATMega328p. I'm already using port B/D and I would like to use port C so that I have extra output pins. My question is, can I use port C as digital output pins without ruining the microcontroller? I know that this port is normally used for analog-digital conversion. If so, do I need to add additional configurations inside my C program?

Comment: It does not have PORT A. Do you mean PORT C?

Comment: Yes, sorry I mean Port C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can I use port A as digital output pins without ruining the
>   microcontroller?

Yes you can.

[image]

Below table describes about Sink and source capabilities:
VOH is when you try to output a high signal. The current should be less than a particular value which you can find in the same table. VOL is when you output a logic zero. Microcontroller can sink current and you should also care about limiting the current. Excess current may lead to damage of the IO Pin or the whole MCU.
[image]

Below are some notes about the analog function rich port C (in some packages, other ports) describing the GPIO capabilities and precautions to be taken.
[image]

> do I need to add additional configurations inside my C program?

Follow the normal routine as configuring other pins.

[image]

Comment: It has been a while since I used this part, but I recall port C being supplied by AVCC instead of VCC for digital functions as well.

Comment: When it is the case, if the user is notnusing analog function, He/She can connect Digital VCC to AVCC as well

Answer (score 1):

An analog pin is actually a normal pin with the alternate function of analog to digital conversion may be activated when needed, so you can use it as a digital pin in case if you don't activate ADC.